# Уместна ли постановка тире в этом предложении?

Tags: запятые, тире

*Пошли, нарубим веток, наберем хвои – вот тебе и факел*

Answer (score 1):

Да, тире - абсолютно, как показатель, что второе предложение является следствием предыдущих. Меня скорее смущает первая запятая. Думаю, что, если ее убрать: *Пошли нарубим веток, наберем хвои – вот тебе и факел* - станет яснее конструкция всего предложения.

Comment: А где там второе предложение? Разве там не одно предложение? "вот тебе и факел" - это вроде как часть предложения. Или я путаю?

Comment: Да, вы правы, правильнее было бы сказать "часть сложного предложения" :)